# Why is Pjax causing a load conflict with html5 video?

Tags: javascript, video, pjax, barbajs

I'm using barba.js to create smooth page transitions with GSAP. Initially I had issues with reinitialising my jS but this is now working (debugged). However, I have an issue with html5 video - clicking on a thumbnail opens a full screen version of the video in a video modal, on a clean page load this doesn't autoplay and has custom controls which are linked to my own jS file - **default controls are hidden**.

For some reason when I switch pages using PJAX and the page reloads the default controls are shown, and my custom video player controls no longer control the video in question. What's weird is they still play the audio, but the video looks like it is overridden by the original file with controls enabled, I can play both videos simultaneously and hear both, but only see one video.

Basically there seems to be incompatibility between PJAX and html5 video, here is my barba.js which controls the PJAX transition (note the reinit of scripts which I have tested and which works):

```
barba.init({

    transitions: [{
        name: 'diffuse-transition',
        leave(data) {
            return gsap.to(data.current.container, {
                opacity: 0
            });
        },

        beforeEnter: ({ next }) => {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            reinitScripts();
        },

        enter(data) {
            return gsap.from(data.next.container, {
                opacity: 0
            });
        }
    }]
});
```

Then the html for the modal:

```
<div id="modalVideoWrapper">
            <div id="modalVideo">
                <div id="modalVideoInner">
                    <video id="modalVideoInteract" src="clients/moo/video/MOO_Advert_Render_v2_2.mp4" preload="auto"
                        poster="clients/moo/images/MOO_Video_Placeholder.jpg" class="projectFeedVideo"></video>
                    <div id="controls">
                        <div id="progressBar"><span id="progress"></span></div>
                        <button id="playpause" title="play" onclick="togglePlayPause()">Play</button>
                    </div>
                    <img class="close-modal" alt="Close" src="assets/icons/icon_close_modal.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then the video modal jS which works perfectly on a full page reload, just not through PJAX:

```
/* Set Globals */
var video = document.getElementById("modalVideoInteract");
/* End Set Globals */
/* Trigger Video Modal */
$(".pF1-Right video, #projectIntro .watchVideo").click(function () {
   $("body").addClass("lock-scroll");
   $("#modalVideoWrapper").fadeTo("slow", 1);
});

$(".close-modal").click(function () {
   video.pause();
   $('#modalVideoInteract').get(0).currentTime = 0.3;
   $("#modalVideoWrapper").fadeOut("300", 0);
   $("body").removeClass("lock-scroll");
});

$("#modalVideoInteract").click(function () {
   $("#playpause").click();
});
/* End Trigger Video Modal */
/* Custom Controls */
video.controls = false;

function togglePlayPause() {
   var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");
   if (video.paused || video.ended) {
      playpause.title = "Pause Video";
      playpause.innerHTML = "Pause";
      video.play();
   }
   else {
      playpause.title = "Play Video";
      playpause.innerHTML = "Play";
      video.pause();
   }
}

function updateProgress() {
   var progress = document.getElementById("progress");
   var value = 0;
   if (video.currentTime > 0) {
      value = Math.floor((100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime);
   }
   progress.style.width = value + "%";
}

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateProgress, false);

video.addEventListener('play', function () {
   var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");
   playpause.title = "Pause Video";
   playpause.innerHTML = "Pause";
}, false);
video.addEventListener('pause', function () {
   var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");
   playpause.title = "Play Video";
   playpause.innerHTML = "Play";
}, false);

video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
   this.pause();
   playpause.title = "Play Again";
   playpause.innerHTML = "Play Again";
}, false);
/* End Custom Controls */
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out, weirdly enough several parts of the page needed to be removed so that they would reinitialise properly, so I added this to the barba transition jS:

```
barba.init({

    transitions: [{
        name: 'diffuse-transition',

        leave(data) {
            return gsap.to(data.current.container, {
                opacity: 0
            });
        },

        beforeEnter: ({ next }) => {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            reinitTitleScene();
            reinitScripts();
        },

        enter(data) {
            return gsap.from(data.next.container, {
                opacity: 0
            });
        },

        afterLeave() {
            reinitModal();
        }
    }]
});

    function reinitTitleScene() {
        $('#titleScene').remove();
    }
    
    function reinitModal() {
        $('#modalVideoInteract').remove();
    }
```

Hope this helps someone in need :)